# Can you transform any coordinate from any "space" to another "space" that's defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transformation, coordinate-systems

This question pertains to Matrix Transformations. So to provide an example, if I have 3D coordinates where $X = -1$ to $1$, $y = -1$ to $1$, $z = -1$ to $1$. They are "normalized" in my mind. Can I use a Matrix to transform these coordinates into a space using "scaling", "rotation", and "translation"? I'm not sure if I'm being specific enough. So if more information is needed. Please feel free to ask. :) Thanks in advance for any responses.

Edit:

To elaborate more on my question; I'm going to tell you what "want" to do because I feel it's right.

What I want to do is take some arbitrary coordinates in 3-D, and transform them into another space that's also 3-D. I have the matrices for this transformation, but I'm not sure if I can just use it directly like that. (I.E. Just multiply these arbitrary coordinates by "my" Matrix and have the results I expects.

Adding more information, Say I have a matrix that is concatenated Scaling, Rotation, and Translation. Can I take this single matrix multiply it with "Any 3D Coordinates that are currently defined in any arbitrary space"? Or, must I take these coordinates, perform "some" operation on them, then use "my" matrix. I hope I make sense. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: You can't write any arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the image of some matrix transformation like that. Do you have a specific subset in mind?

Comment: You're not being specific enough. What do you mean by "transform these coordinates", and by "a space"? Are $x$, $y$, $z$ real number intervals? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Translation is an affine map, by the way, and to use matrices to do that you would have to add a 4th coordinate and consider two normalizations of the same vector to denote the same point, i.e., use homogenous coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your set $C = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x| \le 1, |y| \le 1, |z| \le 1\}$ is a cube, obviously. Using a matrix transformation, you can transform this cube into any given parallelipiped, arbitrarily oriented in space. The matrix transformation will do the necessary rotation, scaling, and shearing. Tell us if that's actually what you want to do, and then the details can be added.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Is that what you're looking for? Note that this is, technically speaking, a reflection, rather than translation, rotation, or scaling.